# Implicit conversion from char to int for constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, implicit-conversion

```
class A {
    int x;
    std::string s;
public:
    A(std::string _s): x(0), s(_s) {
        std::cout << "\tA(string)\n" ;
    }
    A(int _x): x(_x), s("") {
        std::cout << "\tA(int)\n" ;
    }
    A(const A &other): x(other.x), s(other.s) {
        std::cout << "\tA(A& other)\n" ;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello";
    A obj_1(str);
    A obj_2 = str;
    A obj_3(10);
    A obj_4 = 10;
    char ch = 'a';
    A obj_5 = ch;               // How is this working?
    // A obj_6 = "Hello";        // And not this?
    const char *ptr = "Hello";
    // A obj_7 = ptr;            // or this?

    return 0;
}
```

On executing this code, the output is:

```
        A(string)
        A(string)
        A(int)
        A(int)
        A(int)
```

As far as I understand, `obj_1` and `obj_3` are created directly by using the respective ctors. For `obj_2` and `obj_4`, the compiler does an implicit conversion by calling their respective ctor (so only 1 implicit conversion is required in each case). However, for `obj_5` the compiler first has to convert from *char* to *int* and then one more implicit conversion to call the *int*-ctor. But C++ standard allows only 1 implicit conversion. So what is happening here?

Also, in that case `"Hello"` should first get converted to a `std::string` then one more implicit conversion to call the *string*-ctor. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But C++ standard allows only 1 implicit conversion.

Thats not correct.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one standard conversion sequence;
> 2. zero or one user-defined conversion;
> 3. zero or one standard conversion sequence.

From the language point of view, `const char[N]` -> `std::string` (or `const char*` to `std::string`) is a user-defined conversion. Hence, the commented out lines are errors. On the other hand,

```
A obj_5 = ch;               // How is this working?
```

is fine, because there is only a single user-defined conversion involved.